# Definition of Convolution of functions of two variables

Tags: convolution, integral-transforms

We know that, If $f$ and $g$ are functions then their convolution is defined as,

$(f*g)(x) =\int_{-∞}^{∞} f(t)g(x-t) dt$

(This is the convolution structure for Fourier transform)

**But, what if $f$ and $g$ are functions of two variables?** say $f(x, y)$ & $g(x, y)$ then how we can define the convolution in this case? (Please provide reference too)

Update: I have seen many text where it is defined like this,
$$(f*g)(x,y) =\int_{-∞}^{∞}\int_{-∞}^{∞} f(t, s)g(x-t, y-s) dtds$$.

**But I am unable to understand how they arrive at this definition.**

Please help me

Comment: What is the problem in defining it the same way?

Comment: Have you finished multivariable calculus (comfortable with iterated integrals over unbounded domains)? If not then this question is impossible to answer.

Comment: $f*g(x)=\int_{\Bbb R^n}f(t)g(x-t)\mathrm dt$

Comment: @geetha290krm Mam, I have seen some text (research papers) where it is defined in the form of double integral. Further, they didn't mention any source, how they defined it.

Comment: @Sam sir, no I am not completely comfortable with multivariable calculus. But I have done basic course on multivariable calculus in second year of my graduation.

Comment: @SineoftheTime sir how can you explain in details? and please provide reference. As I mentioned in my first comment, I have seen some text where it is defined in terms of double integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is defined entirely analogously: Given two integrable  functions $f,g:\mathbb{R}^n\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$, one defines $$(f*g)(x) := \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(y)g(x-y) dy $$

for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$. As a reference, see e.g. [Convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Domain_of_definition).

Concerning the existence of $(f*g) : \mathbb{R}^n\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$, there are several criteria based on the input functions $f$ and $g$. The easiest one being that if $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $g\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$, then $(f*g)\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ due to [Young's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_convolution_inequality).

Comment: Sir, I have seen many text (research papers) where the  convolution of two functions f(x, y) & g(x, y) is defined as $$(f*g)(x,y) =\int_{-∞}^{∞}\int_{-∞}^{∞} f(t, s)g(x-t, y-s) dtds$$. How they arrive at this definition! Please can you explain. (How double integral comes?)

Comment: @GeneralMathematics Due to the Fubini theorem, one has for an integrable function $f$ that $$\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(x) dx = \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \cdots \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty f(x_1,...,x_n) dx_1\cdots d x_n$$ without any dependency on the order of the 1-dimensional integrals $$\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty f(x_1,...,x_i,...,x_n) d x_i.$$

So for $n=2$, one can write $x=(x_1,x_2)$ and $y=(y_1,y_2)$ which leads to $$\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^2}f(y)g(x-y)dy =  \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty f(y_1,y_2)g(x_1-y_1,x_2-y_2) dy_1 dy_2$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply Sir. Really your comment help me a lot.